# Count records of json object

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to count the records in a JSON object. Getting incorrect count.

**Code**

```
var jsonObject = {"d":"[{\"Country\":\"\",\"CountryCode\":\"\",\"Location\":\"\",\"Group\":\"\",\"RoomMailId\":\"ExchangeRoomTest1@demo.com\",\"Description\":\"\",\"Telephone\":\"\",\"DisplayName\":\"ExchangeRoomTest1\",\"CondecoRoomId\":0,\"CondecoRoomName\":\"\",\"IsMapped\":false,\"LastSyncTimeLocal\":\"\"},{\"Country\":\"\",\"CountryCode\":\"\",\"Location\":\"\",\"Group\":\"\",\"RoomMailId\":\"ExchangeRoomTest2@demo.com\",\"Description\":\"\",\"Telephone\":\"\",\"DisplayName\":\"ExchangeRoomTest2\",\"CondecoRoomId\":0,\"CondecoRoomName\":\"\",\"IsMapped\":false,\"LastSyncTimeLocal\":\"\"}]"};
var keyCount  = Object.keys(jsonObject.d).length
document.write(keyCount);
```

**Output**

489

**Expected Output**

2

Comment: You count number of characters within a string, held by `jsonObject.d`, use `JSON.parse()` to turn the string into array

Comment: There's no such thing as a "JSON Object". What you have there is an object literal with a single property, `d`. This property contains JSON, which means *text* / a String. To turn that into an object, you need to parse that JSON String first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `JSON.parse()` instead of `Object.keys()`

**Note:** `jsonObject.d` is an Array

```js
var jsonObject = {"d":"[{\"Country\":\"\",\"CountryCode\":\"\",\"Location\":\"\",\"Group\":\"\",\"RoomMailId\":\"ExchangeRoomTest1@demo.com\",\"Description\":\"\",\"Telephone\":\"\",\"DisplayName\":\"ExchangeRoomTest1\",\"CondecoRoomId\":0,\"CondecoRoomName\":\"\",\"IsMapped\":false,\"LastSyncTimeLocal\":\"\"},{\"Country\":\"\",\"CountryCode\":\"\",\"Location\":\"\",\"Group\":\"\",\"RoomMailId\":\"ExchangeRoomTest2@demo.com\",\"Description\":\"\",\"Telephone\":\"\",\"DisplayName\":\"ExchangeRoomTest2\",\"CondecoRoomId\":0,\"CondecoRoomName\":\"\",\"IsMapped\":false,\"LastSyncTimeLocal\":\"\"}]"};

var keyCount  = JSON.parse(jsonObject.d).length

document.write(keyCount);
```

Answer (score 2):

`d` is a string, not a parsed array.

```
var keyCount  = Object.keys(JSON.parse(jsonObject.d)).length
document.write(keyCount);
```

Additionally, move away from `document.write()` - it's archaic and has almost no use in modern JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

As you have `stringified` data ,Use `JSON.parse()` to convert it into js object then you can get its length.

```js
var jsonObject = {
  "d": "[{\"Country\":\"\",\"CountryCode\":\"\",\"Location\":\"\",\"Group\":\"\",\"RoomMailId\":\"ExchangeRoomTest1@demo.com\",\"Description\":\"\",\"Telephone\":\"\",\"DisplayName\":\"ExchangeRoomTest1\",\"CondecoRoomId\":0,\"CondecoRoomName\":\"\",\"IsMapped\":false,\"LastSyncTimeLocal\":\"\"},{\"Country\":\"\",\"CountryCode\":\"\",\"Location\":\"\",\"Group\":\"\",\"RoomMailId\":\"ExchangeRoomTest2@demo.com\",\"Description\":\"\",\"Telephone\":\"\",\"DisplayName\":\"ExchangeRoomTest2\",\"CondecoRoomId\":0,\"CondecoRoomName\":\"\",\"IsMapped\":false,\"LastSyncTimeLocal\":\"\"}]"
};
var keyCount = Object.keys(JSON.parse(jsonObject.d)).length;
console.log(keyCount)
```

Answer (score 0):

To count the number key/value pairs in a JSON object we need to convert an array. And then we can easily count the number of element in the array which is same as the number key value pairs in the json object.

Object.keys() returns an array whose elements are strings corresponding to the enumerable properties found in the object.

```
function countObjectKeys(obj) { 
    return Object.keys(obj).length; 
}

//Usage 
var emp = {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"};
console.log(countObjectKeys(emp)); //2
```